# Modify the dom node attributes, and save this segment of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var template = $(this).parent().next().html()
console.log(template)
```

chrome console output

```
<a href="/weishiji/objActivity/timeline/746"><img class="my-pic-head" width="40" height="40" original="/weishiji/avatar/20130121/746.jpg" style="display: block;" src="/weishiji/avatar/20130121/746.jpg"></a>
        <p class="co_reply">
            <a class="co_reply_name" href="/weishiji/objActivity/timeline/746">test</a>
            7                <br>
            <abbr title="2013-01-26 11:11:11" class="publishfooter">56 minute</abbr>
        </p>
        <pre class="delete_reply" id="comment-542">delete</pre>
```

Now I use the following code to modify some of the properties in this html.

```
$(template).find('img').attr('src', 'a')
console.log($(template).html())
```

chrome console output

```
<img class="my-pic-head" width="40" height="40" original="/weishiji/avatar/20130121/746.jpg" style="display: block;" src="/weishiji/avatar/20130121/746.jpg">
```

But this is not the result I wanted, did not change the img src attribute value, and throw away the other node I only want to change the properties inside

Comment: `var $template = $(this).parent().next().clone();
    $template.find('img').prop('src', 'a'); console.log($template.html())`

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you're setting template equal to the html() vs. setting it to the actual object.  Try this instead:

```
var template = $(this).parent().next();
$(template).find('img').attr('src', 'a');
```

Hope this helps.  Here is some sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnWWx/) to see it working.

As @AustinBrunkhorst points out, this would work just the same:

```
template.find('img').attr('src', 'a');
```

Good luck.

Comment: You don't need to wrap `template` with jQuery, as it's already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is , what ever your selecting is already a jquery object so there is no need to re-wrap it again ..

i doubt the there is a problem with the code you have but any how

here is an example

```
var html = $('#id');
var attr = html.find('img').attr('src' , 'somehtm');
console.log(html.html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SxQMw/